# Spacy Model load error from local directory

Tags: nlp, spacy, language-model, spacy-3

I am trying to find a way to load the downloaded `en_core_web_lg ==2.3.1` for `Spacy == 2.3.2`.

Steps:

1. Downloaded the `tar` file
2. extracted it to `path`

Code:

```
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load("path/en_core_web_lg")
```

Error:

```
OSERROR: [E053] Could not read meta.json from en_core_web_lg/meta.json
```

Any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.tar.gz` is a python package, not just a model directory, so you probably need to look one level deeper and load `en_core_web_lg/en_core_web_lg-2.3.1`. You can tell by looking for the directory that contains the subdirectories `vocab`, `tagger`, `ner`, etc.

Comment: There are no such folders, I checked.

Comment: Then maybe something went wrong with the downloading / unpacking. It's easier if you just install the package without unpacking, e.g. `pip install en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz` and then load from the package name (`en_core_web_sm`).